# How to package a Haskell application?

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform

I have written a piece of code that I would like to create a binary and distribute to other folks without having them go through the rigmarole of setting up the Haskell platform and cabal.  Is there a way to statically link the binary in a `cabal build`?

Comment: Use the executable field of the cabal file? The [cabal user guide](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html) is very good for this sort of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run `cabal build`, it links statically by default.